# Get focus on nearest focusable sibling

Tags: android, android-layout, focus, android-tablelayout

In my app on AndroidTV, I have `TableLayout` and `TableRow`. The rows contain the `Button`. When the user taps on a button, the button is disabled. When it happens, I want the focus should go to the nearest focusable view in the `TableLayout`.

The layout is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/input_buttons_row"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/it1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/selection_background"
            android:focusable="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/it2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/selection_background"
            android:focusable="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/it3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/selection_background"
            android:focusable="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/it4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/selection_background"
            android:focusable="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/it5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/selection_background"
            android:focusable="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/it6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/selection_background"
            android:focusable="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/it7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/selection_background"
            android:focusable="true" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Appears as below:
[image]

I am disabling the button on pressing it. So, I want the focus should go to the nearest button in the view. Example: if I press 'Button 5', the focus should go to 'Button 4' or Button 6'. How can I achieve this?

I tried various combinations of request focus on the table row. Example:

```
mInputButtonsRow.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Tried with `requestFocus(View.FOCUS_BACKWARD)` and `requestFocus(View.FOCUS_FORWARD)` as well. The focus jumps to first or the last button in the row, not the nearest focusable button!
But, the focus always goes to the 'Button 1' if it is still enabled. If not, it goes to 'Button 2' and so on. How can I get the focus on the nearest button instead of the first enabled sibling all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several ways but couldn't do it. So, here is the workaround which kind of worked for me. This may not be the best way. I'm still open to a better solution. Here is what I did:
As the user clicks on the button,

```
// Keep the focus on the same button.
mButton1.requestFocus();

// set it to clickable=false
mButton1.setClickable(false);

// Change the background of the button to the disabled button color.
mButton1.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.disabled_button_background));

//Set a FocusChangeListener on the button to disable the button if the focus is changed from it.
mButton1.setOnFocusChangeListener(getButtonFocuslistener());
```

The `FocusChangeListener` is as below:

```
private View.OnFocusChangeListener getButtonFocuslistener() {
        return new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                v.setEnabled(false);
            }
        };
    }
```

**What is happening now:**
As the user clicks on the button, the focus remains on the button, but its color is changed so that it appears like disabled. Since clickable=false is set on it, the user can't click it again. When the user moves the focus on any other view, this button is disabled and so can't get the focus again. So, I could achieve what I was looking for.